# Nested relationships in Room

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have entities:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;
    public String value;
}

@Entity
public class Image {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;
    public String value;
    public long patternId;
    public long itemId;
}

@Entity
public class Pattern {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;
    public String value;
}
```

And relations:

```
public class ItemWithImages {
    @Embedded
    public Item item;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "itemId")
    public List<ImageWithPattern> imageWithPattern;
}

public class ImageWithPattern {
    @Embedded
    public Image image;

    @Embedded
    public Pattern pattern;
}
```

Dao query:

```
Query("SELECT * FROM items LEFT JOIN patterns ON images.patternId = patterns.id")
public abstract Maybe<List<ItemWithImages>> getItems();
```

And here is my error:

> There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing
>   database (no such column: images.pattern_id)

Comment: In case anyone is interested in the answer, check it out [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52554115/4980713)

Comment: @EdyDaoud Why do you keep posing this? This is not the answer to this question

Comment: I am also interested in the right answer for this problem. @PrashanD do you have any ideas you could share?

Comment: @Eduardo https://stackoverflow.com/a/46423137/1800515 worked for me